# I want my buttons to toggle between 2 styles of a particular element such as h1 on clicks, but the button simply disappear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

//this is the body of the html doc. I want my buttons to change the style of h1, like toggle between the color yellow and purple whenever the button is clicked. I tried using the toggle function on the buttons but the buttons disappear in a transition whenever I reload the page.

```
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <button>Click Me</button>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </body>


    //this is the js code. the buttons simply disappear when I reload the page

    $("button").toggle(function() {
        /* Stuff to do every *odd* time the element is clicked */
        $("h1").css("color","purple");
      }, function() {
        /* Stuff to do every *even* time the element is clicked */
        $("h1").css("color","yellow");
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements. So what you are doing is effectively hiding buttons on loading. You need to change your script to something like this.

```
   <script>
      let flag=true;
      $("button").click(function() {
          /* Stuff to do every *odd* time the element is clicked */
          flag ? $("h1").css("color","purple"): $("h1").css("color","yellow");
          flag=!flag;
        });
    </script>
```

Or you can try toggleClass. Define two classes say purple and yellow. Apply purple in the node as

```
<h1 class="purple">Hello</h1>
```

Then in script

```
<script>
      $("button").click(function(){
      $("h1").toggleClass('yellow');
});
</script>
```

This will also work